# How to run jupyter lab in background on windows 10?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

## Question

- I am running Jupyter Lab on windows 10
- The terminal is always turned on after I run Jupyter lab, but I never take a look at the terminal so I want to run the terminal in the background. (The picture below is the terminal that is running, at the same time as Jupyter Lab is running)
  [image]
- How can I run the Jupyter Lab, with the terminal in the background? And how can I turn the background terminal off, on Windows 10?

Comment: How do you launch it? You can suffix a command with `&` to run it in the background, and then close the terminal. You can also use a program like tmux.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Are you sure it is a command that works on windows? As far as I know, that is for Linux and I have tried it and it did not work for me. (reference : https://superuser.com/questions/467012/command-prompt-run-scripts-in-background-equivalent-of-linuxs-bg)

Comment: how are you launching jupyter lab?

Comment: [jupyterlab-desktop](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop) would be one solution - but it's early in development (just revived) and needs contributors to gain full functionality.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I typed 'jupyter lab' on terminal (windows cmd)

Comment: @krassowski I have tried that but it does not support extensions yet, so I am not using it at the moment.

Comment: does `start /B "" jupyter lab` work?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Yes it does. However, if I turn of the terminal, the jupyter lab does not work anymore. So it seems that the terminal is not running in the back ground.